# How to convert a set of BitmapDatas into video?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, ffmpeg

I basically need to record a video of the flash stage, and save it as a video file on the webserver. I don't have FMS or the luxury of Java based servers like Red5 to stream to, so I am pretty much stuck with HTTP post to a php script. Now I can grab invidual snapshots (bitmapDatas) Just fine, but how can I convert them to a video file? Any help is appreciated.

PS: This is not an AIR app, so I am using flash runtime. And the video would be couple seconds long so there shouldn't be much of a performance concern at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Flex provide a JPEG encoder. You can use that to compress the bitmap images and send them to the server, where you can that stitch them together using ffmpeg.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/graphics/codec/JPEGEncoder.html

Comment: isn't it possible to convert to bytearray and send that instead? and wouldn't encoding to png be better compared to jpeg?

Comment: Well, use PNGEncoder instead if quality is an issue and bandwidth is no problem. The result from both encoder is going to a ByteArray.